# How to limit the number of cpus in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu

Is there a way to limit the number of cpus used at boot time?  I have a four core machine and would like to limit the number of cpus to obtain stats on a multi-threaded program.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to have this at boot time? Rather than simply pinning a certain process at a certain time to a number of CPUs?

If you can do the latter, then look in to CPU affinity under linux. There's different utilities that will let you do that for specific processes.

Comment: The utility in particular to investigate is [`taskset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do that via a BIOS setting but that is motherboard specific.